# How to access route params in Vue routes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Using Vue 2, I'm trying to access one of the route's params within the route definitions themselves. In this case, I want to access the passed in district_id and use it in the beforeEnter method.

```
{
    path     : '/dashboard/:district_id/',
    redirect : '/dashboard/:district_id/home',
    name     : 'DashboardHome',
    component: DashboardContainer,
    meta     : {
      label       : 'Dashboard',
      requiresAuth: true,
    },
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      const hasAccess = store.state.currentUser.districts.includes(district_id);
      if (hasAccess) {
        next()
      } else {
        next('/403');
      }
    },
```

Comment: This is what hook parameters are for. Did you try to.params.district_id?

Comment: Both `to` and `from` are [route objects](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object). Read the linked documentation for a full list of their available properties. As @estusflask pointed out, the current `district_id` value is in `to.params.district_id`.